# how to solve the progress bar retrieve data from firebase Store and navigation bottom bar | kotlin

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-alertdialog, android-progressbar

it work fine when I login in, the progress bar will show on the screen.[In the Home tab]
But every time I go to **Account tab** then go back the **Home tab fragment** it will keep appear even the data it exist in the **Home fragment tab**

I use `loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog()` and `loadingDialog.dismissDialog()` between `c.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED`.

If I try use **handle** to delay thread, when u swipe to the home tab you need to wait long, so diasable it

**Home Fragment**

```
  private fun EventChangeListener() {

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        db.collection("FlashSalesProducts")
            .addSnapshotListener(object : EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
                override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        Log.e("Firestore Error", error.message.toString())
                        return
                    }

                    loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog()
                    for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                        if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {  // Log.i("xxxxFromFireStoreRetrieveProductList:", productList.toString())

                            productList.add(dc.document.toObject(Products::class.java))    //isFavour = null(get from FlashSlaes firebaseStore,settle in future

                        }
                    }
                    productsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    loadingDialog.dismissDialog()
//                    var handle : Handler = Handler()
//                    handle.postDelayed({ },1500)

                }
            })

    }
```

**Loading Dialog**

```
package com.example.myecommerceapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater

class LoadingDialog(private val activity : Activity) {

    private lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

    val TAG = "xxxxxxDialog"

    fun startLoadingDialog(){
        var builder : AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        var inflater : LayoutInflater = activity.layoutInflater
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_loading, null))
        builder.setCancelable(false)
        dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
        Log.i(TAG,"dialog show")
    }

    fun dismissDialog(){
        dialog.dismiss()
        Log.i(TAG,"dialog dismiss")
    }

}
```

**MainActivity** to handle all navigation bar fragment

```
package com.example.myecommerceapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.example.myecommerceapp.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.myecommerceapp.ui.Account.AccountFragment
import com.example.myecommerceapp.ui.home.HomeFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
    private val accountFragment: AccountFragment = AccountFragment()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> replaceFragment(homeFragment)

                R.id.navigation_account -> replaceFragment(accountFragment)
            }
            true
        }


    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (binding.bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId == R.id.navigation_home) {
            super.onBackPressed()
        } else {
            binding.bottomNavigationView.selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_home
        }
    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
           supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.Fragmentcontainer,
                fragment,
                fragment.javaClass.simpleName // retrive name as Tag
            )
                .commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is hard coded. The way you implement the fragment call may be they are recreated every time you change destination. Try to implement this with **Architecture Components** (ex. Use MVVM/MVI) . For navigation use latest version of **Navigation Components** which is now supports backstack

Comment: can you teach me how to implement it, I am new to this, I don't know how to use MVVM/MVI